# Specifying axis line thickness with magicaxis

Tags: r, plot

With base R, one can do

```
axis(1, lwd=2)
```

to get a thicker x-axis line.

With magicaxis, however, this does not do the trick:

```
library(magicaxis)
magaxis(1, lwd=2)
```

does not change the line thickness. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package author here. Yes, when you wrote this lwd was not directly accessible like that (there was a working around by setting a global par). You can now pass in a whole variety of different lwd (lines, grid, ticks, etc) in magaxis and magplot. Have a look at the latest version man pages.